# Magento 2 CLI is broken

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am getting an issue anytime I try to use the magento 2 CLI:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We had issues similar to this and magento support recommended a full reinstall using composer. If you're on a fresh install, thats probably your best bet. From the html directory, try running php bin/magento and see if your list of commands comes up, if that fails a reinstall is probably a must. Go ahead and remove the folders that they specified before, but if you aren't able to run bin/magento setup:upgrade, you need to reinstall.

Comment: This isn't a fresh install.  we just finished transferring over a massive amount of products, and have a considerable amount of development work in the project so far.  I really hope that a solution might exist that would save the work so far.  I have a backup but it doesn't cover about a week's worth of dev work.